# Proof of necessary and sufficient conditions for unitary equivalence when n=3

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, reference-request

The wikipedia article on [Specht's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specht%27s_theorem) lists a minimal set of seven traces that need to be equal to confirm the unitary equivalence of two complex-valued matrices, $A$ and $B$, for the case $n=3$.

The reference in wikipedia points to an article [1] in Russian that I cannot find online (I also don't know Russian so I imagine it wouldn't be of great help in any case). Meanwhile reference [2] shows that a certain set consisting of **nine** traces is sufficient, so I am interested in why two of them are redundant.

If the traces of the following nine elements are equal, whether $X$ takes the value of $A$ or $B$ (so that e.g. $tr(A) = tr(B)$), then $A$ and $B$ are unitarily equivalent:

$X, X^2, XX^{*}, X^3, X^2X^{*}, X^2(X^{*})^2, X^{*}X^2X^{*}X, X^{*}XX^{*}X, X^2(X^{*})^2AA^{*}$.

But the following two are apparently redundant:

$X^{*}XX^{*}X, X^{*}X^2X^{*}X$.

Can someone provide me with a proof, or even an outline of a proof, of why these two are redundant? A reference would be enough if it is available online in English.

[1] Sibirskiǐ, K. S. (1976), Algebraic Invariants of Differential Equations and Matrices (in Russian), Izdat. "Štiinca", Kishinev

[2] Pearcy, C. (1962). A complete set of unitary invariants for 3× 3 complex matrices. Transactions of the American Mathematical Society, 104(3), 425-429.

Comment: If there is anything I can do to improve this question please feel free to comment.